# R data visualization with ggplot2 - adding colors to 20 variables with RColorBrewer

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize data with ggplot2, and add 20 different colors to the 20 categories I have in "description". Without the colors, the script works perfectly (only black). However, in any way I want to add color it either stays black, or with the script below I get the following error:
`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2265723): colour`
This should not be a problem, as "Pastel1" has 255 colors and I created a lenght variable.

dataset (description has 20 categories):

```
chr pos p description
1 445578 0.05 Metabolic
3 659990 0.34 Metabolic
5 789689 0.55 Immunological
6 678599 0.05 BodyStructures
7 97890 0.67 Cardiovascular
2 67899 0.01 Hematological
8 9867647 0.34 Nutritional
3 675890 0.55 Environment
6 799030 0.76 Psychiatric
4 8609000 0.88 Cognitive
6 789900 0.12 Musculoskeletal
3 90907878 0.22 Opthalmological
```

```
colourCount = length(unique(dataset$description))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Pastel1"))
```

```
Nean_PheWAS <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=description, y=-log(p), colour = getPalette(colourCount))) + 
geom_jitter(mapping=aes(x=as.factor(description), y=-log10(p))) +
theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour = "grey", linetype="dashed"), axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
labs(color="description", size="Effect size", x="Phenotype Classes", y="log(p-value)") +
geom_hline(yintercept=-log(0.01), color="red", size=1, alpha=0.5)
```

I am also open to other solutions to add 20 different colors to the categories.

Comment: I think you're supposed to map `colour` to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you wish to colour by the variable `description`, you can use the ColorBrewer palette with `colourCount` number of elements by adding `scale_colour_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount))` to the ggplot object. And change `colour = description` in the aesthetics:

```r
colourCount = length(unique(dataset$description))
getPalette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Pastel1"))
Nean_PheWAS <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=description, y=-log(p), colour = description)) + 
geom_jitter(mapping=aes(x=as.factor(description), y=-log10(p))) +
theme_classic() + scale_colour_manual(values = getPalette(colourCount)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
panel.grid.minor=element_line(colour = "grey", linetype="dashed"), axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
labs(color="description", size="Effect size", x="Phenotype Classes", y="log(p-value)") +
geom_hline(yintercept=-log(0.01), color="red", size=1, alpha=0.5)
```